# Inline "onclick" function is not called

Tags: javascript

I have string html and will be append :

```
var str = "<fieldset><p class='error' id='pMessage'>You was login sucessful.</p><a id='btnLogout' onclick='logoutAccount('nhattruong@gmail.com');'  href='#'>Logout</a></fieldset>";
$("#divLogin").html(str);
```

And method event

```
function logoutAccount(mail)
{
   alert(mail);
}
```

My problem is : a tag event click is not working ?

Comment: `onclick='logoutAccount('nhattruong@gmail.com');'` Look at your quotation marks. Where does the `onclick` value terminate?

Comment: a simple look in browser console at error thrown would be a good place to start

Comment: @cookiemonster Whoops, that was my edit mistake. Fixed.

Comment: @jeekonline: Trouble is that that will terminate the main string prematurely. You should escape those double quotes.

Comment: change to this : onclick='logoutAccount("nhattruong@gmail.com");'

Comment: @jeekonline: Same issue. Remember that it's part of the `str` string literal that's delineated using `"`, so you need to escape them `onclick='logoutAccount(\"nhattruong@gmail.com\");'`

Comment: @cookiemonster: you are correct!

Comment: [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820)

Answer (score 1):

check this

**Html**

```
<div id="feeds"></div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var email = 'nhattruong@gmail.com';
var str = "<fieldset><p class='error' id='pMessage'>You was login sucessful.</p><a id='btnLogout' onclick=logoutAccount('"+email+"');   href='#'>Logout</a></fieldset>";
$("#feeds").html(str);

function logoutAccount(mail)
{
   alert(mail);
}
</script>
```

**Updated**

**Another Choice**

```
onclick=\"logoutAccount('nhattruong@gmail.com');\"
```

**Full code view**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//var email = 'nhattruong@gmail.com';
var str = "<fieldset><p class='error' id='pMessage'>You was login sucessful.</p><a id='btnLogout' onclick=\"logoutAccount('nhattruong@gmail.com');\"   href='#'>Logout</a></fieldset>";
$("#feeds").html(str);

function logoutAccount(mail)
{
   alert(mail);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know if removing the quotes from around the `onclick` attribute's values is going to be the best solution. You'll be better off with some escaping.

Comment: I think that's safer. You really don't need the separate `email` variable, but doesn't matter I guess.

Comment: @cookie monster  Ya you tell me correct.  onclick=\"logoutAccount('nhattruong@gmail.com');\"  this one is also worked

Answer (score 1):

You need the different quotation with variable and Function

`onclick='logoutAccount(\"nhattruong@gmail.com\");'`